# how to visualize control characters

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts

Modern text editors like Notepad++ can visualize control characters like `CR`, `LF`, `STX`, `ETX`, `EOT`. I have started to wonder **how text editors visualize these characters so neatly.**

[image: visualization of CRLF characters]

*Note: I am familiar with how encodings and character sets work. And I'm also familiar with the reason why these characters exist.*

**Some ideas:**

1. Does it **apply a special font** for these specific characters ?
   i.e. a font which contains a representation of *all* characters.
2. Or does it use **an advanced text-field control/gui-component** that renders (i.e. draws) them on the canvas ?
3. Or does it just **replace the characters** ? (e.g. replacing a `0x0D` with unicode character `0x240D` i.e. `␍`)
   This seems to be the easiest. But then how does it preserve the fact that copying the text still keeps the original text.

**The reason for my question:** I would like to create a java application that does the same thing.

Comment: The application concerned will look at the control characters in the text, and convert them to strings to be displayed. E.G. `0x0D` = 'CR'

Comment: see point 2 of my question. "But then ..."

Comment: You can use this alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43416931/2073804

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some inherent problems with assigning *glyphs* ('images') to Control Codes; most have to do with the case that they already have a particular use! For example, if you send a Tab code to your display, you'd typically expect the cursor to move by a certain number of positions and not to see a character `○` pop up.

Also, typically, fonts use Unicode as their native encoding. Unicode does not allow a glyph to be assigned to the control codes:

> Sixty-five code points (U+0000–U+001F and U+007F–U+009F) are reserved as control codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

There is an 'alias' sort of set defined: U+2400 to U+241F for `0x00` to `0x1f`, U+2420 "␠" for "symbol for space", and U+2421 "␡" for "symbol for Delete" (your #3) but then you need to make sure the user has a font that contains these glyphs.

The most configurable way is to 'manually' draw whatever you like. This means you can use any font you want (without the need for a special font), and character replacement is not necessary (only the drawing code need to filter out 'specials'). A drawback, though, is that you are also in charge of drawing *regular* text.

If that is overkill or you don't have sufficient control over the text draw area, you can simply use different foreground and background colors for the control characters only. This is a screenshot of a quick-and-dirty hex viewer I wrote a while ago – I only change the colors here, but I could have written out custom text for all as well.

[image: QuikRead display dialog]

For a good overview of what it takes, see James Brown's [Design & Implementation of a Win32 Text Editor](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/neatpad); it focuses on using Win32 API calls but there is a lot of background as well. Drawing neat Control Codes is addressed in the section [Enhanced Drawing & Painting](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/enhanced-drawing-painting).

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd idea should be true, you can replace the charaters with [unicode control pictures](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2400.pdf) using a proper font.